# Select statement to return values from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I am writing a stored procedure with the following parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDateRange
    @InvNo      varchar(50) OUTPUT,
    @InvDt      date        OUTPUT,
    @InvDueDt   date        OUTPUT,
    @InvTot     money       OUTPUT,
    @InvBal     money       OUTPUT,
    @minDate    varchar(30) = NULL,
    @maxDate    varchar(30) = NULL
AS...
```

after validating I am trying to do the following SELECT for the resultset:

```
SELECT
    @InvNo,
    @InvDt,
    @InvDueDt,
    @InvTot,
    (InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal) AS @InvBal --SYNTAX ERROR
FROM
    Invoices
WHERE
    InvoiceDate >= @minDate
    AND InvoiceDate <= @maxDate
ORDER BY
    InvoiceDate;
```

I want to calculate the balance due and pass it back along with columns from tables that meet the criteria.

Also, is the return of these parameters implied? I am not using a return value (integer).

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: So what have you tried? What is not working? What is your database platform?

Comment: SQL Server 2019 - apologies and thank you for adding markup for displaying as code - still learning how to do this.

Comment: `@InvBal =  (InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal)` But you have to be sure that query returns single row otherwise it does not have much sense.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Please show show sample data + expected results (and clarify how to handle the fact that multiple invoices could included). Also please read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as that clearly explains how to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is flawed, you are not assigning any values to your variables (that presumably you want to return) and you will need to specify top 1

for example

```
SELECT top 1
    @InvNo=InvNo,
    @InvDt=InvDt,
    @InvDueDt=InvDueDt,
    @InvTot=InvTot,
    @InvBal=(InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal)
FROM
    Invoices
WHERE
    InvoiceDate >= @minDate
    AND InvoiceDate <= @maxDate
ORDER BY
    InvoiceDate;
```

The variables, once assigned a value, will be returned to the calling proc (output clause also required on the parameters)

Comment: Thank you sTTu!
I'm trying to follow along in Murach's book and the examples were confusing me. Much appreciated.

Comment: This will return only one result.

Comment: It appears someone does not agree and has down-voted

Comment: @Metaphor how many results can a parameter return?

Comment: OP's question reflects his desire for multiple results. OP is very obviously very new to SQL.  "I want to calculate the balance due and pass it back along with columns from tables that meet the criteria."

Answer (score 0):

Use date type parameters. Don't use char types for dates.

Return column values, not variables

Alias (AS) can't be a variable

Test for NULL in where for @minDate and @maxDate since you are using
optional params

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDateRange
    @minDate    DATETIME2(0) = NULL,
    @maxDate    DATETIME2(0) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        i.InvNo,
        i.InvDt,
        i.InvDueDt,
        i.InvTot,
        InvoiceTotal - CreditTotal - PaymentTotal AS InvBal
    FROM Invoices i
    WHERE 
        (@minDate IS NULL OR InvoiceDate >= @minDate)
        AND (@maxDate IS NULL OR InvoiceDate <= @maxDate)
    ORDER BY InvDate
END
```